# macOS command line app - User Defaults dictionaryRepresentation shows too many values

Tags: xcode, macos, nsuserdefaults

I a developing a macOS commandline application in Xcode, which uses User Defaults. I have the following code for my User Defaults

```
if let configDefaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "com.tests.configuration") {
    configDefaults.set("myStringValue", forKey: "stringKey")
    configDefaults.synchronize()
    print(configDefaults.dictionaryRepresentation())
}
```

This will create my own `.plist` file in the `~/Library/Preferences` folder. If I look into the file, I can see only my single value which I added, which is perfectly fine. But when I call `dictionaryRepresentation()` on my UserDefaults object, the there are a lot of other attributes (I guess from the shared UserDefaults object), like

`com.apple.trackpad.twoFingerFromRightEdgeSwipeGesture` or `AKLastEmailListRequestDateKey`

Looking into the documentation of UserDefaults, it seems that this has to do with the search list of UserDefaults and that the `standard` object is in the search list:

> `func dictionaryRepresentation() -> [String : Any]`
>
> Returns a dictionary that contains a union of all key-value pairs in the domains in the search list.

There are also the methods `addSuite` and `removeSuite` for a UserDefaults object, so I am guessing I need to remove the `.standard` suite from my `configDefaults` object, but I don't know the name, which should be used for that in the method.

Is it possible to remove the `.standard` defaults from the dictionary representation? I basically just want all of my own data in a dictionary, nothing more.

The reason I am trying to get only my values from the UserDefaults, is that a have a number of object of a custom type `Connection` (which store the configuration to connect to a server), which are saved in the UserDefaults. On program start I want to be able to load all objects into my app. Therefore I thought I could use `dictionaryRepresentation()`, as it would return all elements in the UserDefaults. But then there should be only my `Connection` objects in the dictionary, so that I can cast it to `[String: Connection]`.

Comment: Please read the documentation of [UserDefaults.standard](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416603-standard);

Comment: Do you writa anything to User Defaults? Please post your code.

Comment: Why do you care what's in the `dictionaryRepresentation`? What are you hoping to use it for? It's an unusual thing to care about and if you explain we may be able to set you on a better course. In the meantime, you can probably get what you're looking for using `persistentDomain(forName:)` with your program's bundle ID as the name.

Comment: @KenThomases thank you, I've updated my question, explaining why I want to use `dictionaryRepresentation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your purpose (in your latest edit of your question), what you should do is store a collection of `Connection` objects under a single key. Then, look up that key to get the collection.

It's not clear if the collection should be an array of `Connection` objects or a dictionary mapping strings to `Connection`s. That's a choice you can make.

But, in any case, you shouldn't rely on the defaults being empty of everything else.

In other words, you would do:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(yourStringToConnectionDictionary, forKey:"yourSingleKey")
```

and later:

```
let connectionMap = UserDefaults.dictionary(forKey:"yourSingleKey")
```

then look up `Connection`s in the `connectionMap` by their name/ID/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Though the other solution proposed by Ken Thomases may be better from a design standpoint, I've found a solution that does exactly what I initially wanted. Calling

```
UserDefaults.standard.persistentDomain(forName: "com.company.TestApp.configuration")
```

Returns a dictionary containing only the values I've added to the domain `com.company.TestApp.configuration`, using

```
let configs = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "com.company.TestApp.configuration")!
configs.set(someData, forKey: someKey)
```

Strangely in the Apple documentation says this about `persistentDomain(forName:)`:

> Calling this method is equivalent to initializing a user defaults object with `init(suiteName:)` passing domainName and calling the `dictionaryRepresentation()` method on it.

But this is not the case (see my question). Clarification on that subject is more than welcome.